# Downloading Blob via http using AngularJS and Angular-FileSaver.js

Tags: angularjs, filesaver.js

I'm having a **really hard time** solving this problem. I've tried so many different solutions that I'm not sure where I need to fix now. I'm attempting to retrieve a Blob via http get and download the file for a user using FileSaver.js
For some reason, every time I attempt to open the image I get a "damaged, corrupted, or is too large" message. I've attempted playing with the 'responseType' (changing to 'blob'), adding an 'Accept' to the header. Nothing seems to work for me!!

Can somebody maybe point me in the right direction?

**Service**

```
download: function(blobId, token) {
  var req = {
    method: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url: 'api/Blob/DownloadBlob/' + blobId,
    headers: {
     'responseType': 'arraybuffer',
     'Authorization': token
    }
  };

  return $http(req)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response;
    }, function(response) {
      // something went wrong
      return $q.reject(response.data);
  });
}
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.downloadFile = function () {
  Data.download($scope.blobId, $scope.token).then(function (response) {
    var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'image/png' });
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'download.png');
  });
};
```

Comment: `responseType` is **not** a header. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

Comment: FileSaver will not work for Safari or iOS Safari browsers. I believe it should work in Safari 10.1 on the Mac because that version says it supports the download attribute in the anchor tag (what filesaver uses under the hood)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First two problems I can see are...

1. The `responseType` config property should not be in the `headers` object
2. You are passing the `response` object to the `Blob` constructor where you probably want to pass `response.data`.

I'd go with

```
return $http.get('api/Blob/DownloadBlob/' + blobId, {
  responseType: 'blob',
  headers: {
   Authorization: token
  },
  transformResponse: function(data) {
    return data // there's no need to attempt any transformations
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  return response.data // your provider consumers only need the blob data
})
```

and in your consumer...

```
Data.download($scope.blobId, $scope.token).then(function(blob) {
  FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'download.png')
})
```

Comment: FileSaver will not work for Safari or iOS Safari browsers. I believe it should work in Safari 10.1 on the Mac because that version says it supports the download attribute in the anchor tag (what filesaver uses under the hood).

Comment: @Patrick I suggest you add your comment to the question above so Nick can see it. He's the one using FileSaver, not me

Comment: I up voted the answer just as well. I'm also using FileSaver, so wanted to make sure those limitations were known if he needs to support those browsers.